# How can I provoke a DetachedInstanceError with ZopeTransactionExtension for unit tests

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope, pytest

I am currently writing unit tests for my application and I have a common error where a function wants to access a database object after the session is already closed up. To make sure this error does not exist in the application, I want to deliberately trigger it. If I have it, I fix the error and make sure its gone for good.

However, I seem to have a hard time doing this:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(
                sessionmaker(
                    extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(),
                    ))
db_session = DBSession()
obj = Object()
db_session.add(obj)
obj.property = "a"
db_session.expire_on_commit = True
db_session.expire(obj)
db_session.expunge(obj)
transaction.commit()
db_session.close()
assert obj.property == "a"
```

This is a short example of what's going on. I would expect that either `transaction.commit` or `db_session.close()` trigger the excpetion but not even the combined code above (which, from googling, seems to be all sources of the error combined) can trigger this exception.

The real error comes from this: I have a database stored session and once I want to set the session ID in the cookie, the session says its detached. So I will just cache it locally, it's not like I its going to change after it was created.

Finally, when trying to expire it on purpose like so:

```
assert obj in db_session
db_session.expire(obj)
```

I get an exception: `InvalidRequestError: Instance ... is not persistent within this Session`. This then puzzles me completely... And here googling does not reveal anything helpful. Any ideas?

**Edit**: Thanks to zzzeek's comment I also tested:

```
assert db_session is \
        orm.session.Session.object_session(obj)
assert isinstance(obj, Object)
assert isinstance(Object.property, orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute)
```

*Note*: All code examples are shortended and transformed but these operations are executed this way and all `assert` statements hold true.

**Edit 2**: I had to fix a mistake in my code above and replaced

```
obj = db_session.query(Object)[0] # Object is from DB, just a short example
```

by

```
obj = Object()
db_session.add(obj)
```

because it actually newly creates the object instead of querying it. Query works find (Sorry!)

**Edit 3**: Somehow along the way I fixed the original problem: I can now force the exception I initially wanted. However, I still get the unexplained `InvalidRequestError` and so I decided to make a basic gist that demonstrates the problem: https://gist.github.com/Javex/5885669. You can either run it as a standlone script or through `py.test`.

Comment: Assuming `obj.property` is mapped and has been expired, seems like its present in another session (which shouldn't be possible given that code example).  Use the object_session(obj) function to retrieve the Session which the object is actually attached to.  Otherwise I'd bet that expire_on_commit is turned off, or ".property" isn't managed by the ORM.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made an edit above and made sure everything is fine with what you said. Also I assume its okay to set `expire_on_commit` directly on an instance of `Session` (as the `__init__` would just set this attribute itself upon initialization according to the source code)?

Comment: can you produce a full reproducing example for this?  its not possible to get the "instance not persistent in this session" error if the object is in fact reported as being in that session by object_session().

Comment: I have created a gist (see Edit 3). Also note, that my original problem is resolved (and I had an error in my original question). However, the new `InvalidRequestError` thing still stands so my gist now only reflects that (I wasn't even able to reproduce the other problem...)

Comment: the message is correct - the object is not persistent, it is pending.  it has not been flushed.   As a side note I'd maybe try to use more distinct object names, the names here are very difficult to follow.

Comment: ah okay so flushing was the problem - thank you